# Trouble getting PrintWritter to correctly print to .txt after my nested loop

Tags: java, nested, printf, printwriter

I'm asked to use PrintWriter to print grids of multiplication problems to a .txt file.  Everything is working well but I'm having some serious trouble with getting my code to print the way I'm asked.  I've been using printf with left/right indentation.  Any help would be very appreciated.

I didn't realize that my account wouldn't upload pictures so sorry about the confusion. I had thought I posted the output needed. This is how it should look.

Basically it's creating 3 columns of numbers by 10 rows.  I can get this to work but without the separation of columns and rows.  The left side is the odd numbers with the right side being the even.

```
1 * 1 = 1                 1 * 2 = 2
2 * 1 = 2                 2 * 2 = 4
3 * 1 = 3                 3 * 2 = 6
4 * 1 = 4                 4 * 2 = 8
ect
10 * 1 = 10              10 * 2 = 20



1 * 3 = 3
2 * 3 = 6
ext.....




import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;

public class LabPrintTimeTables {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
        printTimeTable();

}

private static void printTimeTable() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    try {
        File file = new File ("Lab Print Time Table");

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("TimeTables.txt");

        printWriter.println ("\tTimes Tables:\n");
        for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++ )
            {
                if (i % 10 == i) {
         System.out.printf("%-2d * %-2d = %-2d", j, i + i + 1, i   * j + 1);
         System.out.printf("%10d * %d = %d\n", j, i + i + 2, i * j + 1);
                }


            }

        }
        printWriter.close ();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Edit your post to include some context. What is your expected output? What is your actual output?

Comment: Why are you using a PrintWriter to write to a file but printing to stdout the actual contents? For debugging purposes?

Comment: Yeah, I used it just to more quickly see the results of any changes I made to the nested loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not writing to the `printWriter`, but to Console only. Write to `printWriter` object also in inner `for` loop to store the content in file. Like.

```
for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++ )
            {
                if (i % 10 == i) {
         System.out.printf("%-2d * %-2d = %-2d", j, i + i + 1, i   * j + 1);
         System.out.printf("%10d * %d = %d\n", j, i + i + 2, i * j + 1);

         printWriter.printf("%-2d * %-2d = %-2d", j, i + i + 1, i
                            * j + 1);
         printWriter.printf("%10d * %d = %d\n", j, i + i + 2, i
                            * j + 1);
                }
```

### EDIT

I hope you tried to get the desired output, but if you still have the problem then here you go.

```
private static void printTimeTable() throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        File file = new File("Lab Print Time Table");

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("TimeTables.txt");

        printWriter.println("\tTimes Tables:\n");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 2) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {

                System.out.printf("%-2d * %-2d = %-2d", j, i, i * j);
                System.out
                        .printf("%10d * %d = %d\n", j, i + 1, j * (i + 1));

                printWriter.printf("%-2d * %-2d = %-2d", j, i, i * j);
                printWriter.printf("%10d * %d = %d\n", j, i + 1, j
                        * (i + 1));

            }
            System.out.println("");

            printWriter.println("");
        }
        printWriter.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

Comment: My bad I started printing to consul because it was faster to see any changes I made. Either way I can't seem to get the correct output.

Comment: So your problem is with the output result not with writing the output to file?

Comment: Yeah, it prints to output as long as I use printWriter where system.out is. It's getting the same looking format I'm struggling with.

Comment: I just updated the question with the results that are needed.